# matplotlib artist animation : title or text not changing

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I tried using matplotlib's ArtistAnimation.   The text and titles of the figure are supposed to change in each frame, but they don't. 
I have read tons of posts on similar problems, but I still don't understand what is the solution. The demos don't show updating titles as far as I could find.

If anybody out there knows, I would be grateful!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig =plt.figure()    
ims=[]

for iternum in range(4):
    plt.title(iternum)
    plt.text(iternum,iternum,iternum)
    ims.append([plt.scatter(np.random.randint(0,10,5), np.random.randint(0,20,5),marker='+'    )])
    #plt.cla()


ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, blit=False,
                              repeat_delay=2000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To animate artists, you have to return a reference to each artists in your `ims[]` array, including the `Text` objects.

**However it doesn't work for the title**, I don't know why. Maybe somebody with a better understanding of the mechanisms involved will be able to enlighten us.

Nevertheless, the title is just a `Text` object, so we can produce the desired effect using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ims=[]

for iternum in range(4):
    ttl = plt.text(0.5, 1.01, iternum, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom', transform=ax.transAxes)
    txt = plt.text(iternum,iternum,iternum)
    ims.append([plt.scatter(np.random.randint(0,10,5), np.random.randint(0,20,5),marker='+'    ), ttl, txt])
    #plt.cla()


ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, blit=False,
                              repeat_delay=2000)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the explanation and code ! I spent more than three hours trying to do that, and I don't think I would've been able to do it at all.  I wish they would put an example like this one you just did in the matplotlib animation tutorial  :-)

Comment: NameError: name 'ax' is not defined

Answer (score 7):

You need to supply the artists to animate as a list of sequences to the `ArtistAnimation`. In the code from the question you only supply the scatter, but not the text and title.
Unfortunately the title is also part of the axes and thus will not change even if supplied. So you may use a normal text instead.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ims=[]

for iternum in range(4):
    title = plt.text(0.5,1.01,iternum, ha="center",va="bottom",color=np.random.rand(3),
                     transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize="large")
    text = ax.text(iternum,iternum,iternum)
    scatter = ax.scatter(np.random.randint(0,10,5), np.random.randint(0,20,5),marker='+')
    ims.append([text,scatter,title,])


ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, blit=False,
                              repeat_delay=2000)
plt.show()
```

You may consider using `FuncAnimation` instead of `ArtistAnimation`. This would allow to change the title easily.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ims=[]

text = ax.text(0,0,0)
scatter = ax.scatter(np.random.randint(0,10,5), np.random.randint(0,20,5),marker='+')


def update(iternum):
    plt.title(iternum)
    text.set_position((iternum, iternum))
    text.set_text(str(iternum))
    scatter.set_offsets(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,2)))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=4, interval=500, blit=False,
                              repeat_delay=2000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly! I'll have to work a bit further to understand this concept of artists.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you draw a line and get a `Line2D` object. Then you use `Line2D.set_data` to update the line. The data (and thus the position of the line) is changing while the object is the same one, so when you do `ArtistAnimation`, different frames will show the same object, which contains the most updated information.

Now come to the title. The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title) says that

> Set one of the three available Axes titles. The available titles are positioned above the Axes in the center, flush with the left edge, and flush with the right edge.

and the source code is

```
titles = {'left': self._left_title,
          'center': self.title,
          'right': self._right_title}
title = _api.check_getitem(titles, loc=loc.lower())
```

It is the same situation. The `Title` object is pre-constructed and only its content (instead of the object) is updated. When you do `ArtistAnimation`, only the last update works.

To avoid this, as @Diziet Asahi and @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested, using `Text` or `FuncAnimation`.